# A better way to implement in-memory-cache in javascript / nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, v8

I had a question. The following code has a memory leak:

```
let inMemoryCache = {};

app.get("/hello",(req, resp) => {
   inMemoryCache[unixTimeStamp] = {"foo":"bar"}
   resp.json({});
});
```

Isn't it? The size of the object `inMemoryCache` will keep on increasing with each request until it hits the ceiling and the heap size explodes.

What then is the best to implement in-memory-caches?

Answer (score 2):

Manage the size of your cache somehow. For example, you could keep a fixed number of entries, and once the cache has reached its maximum size and a new entry comes in, delete the oldest (or least frequently used, or least recently used, or some other selection criteria).

Caching is harder than it seems :-)

Comment: Yeah, I realized this recently. I was reading about `weakmap` While I am not clear enough, but does that help here?

Comment: WeakMaps don't keep their contents "alive" in the GC sense, i.e. if there are no other references to them, then the next GC cycle will clear them. Whether that's desirable behavior very much depends on what you want your cache to do.

Comment: I specifically want to cache the results from database calls. Like big JSON documents. What will you suggest?

Comment: I don't know enough about your situation to recommend something specific, so I can only recommend a generic strategy: try any one approach that seems reasonable to you, measure how well it works, and if it's not satisfactory, try something else. Repeat as needed.

Comment: Yeah, doing the same!

Comment: A `WeakMap` won't help with caching here, as you cannot use a timestamp as a key in them.

Comment: Bergi: sure; that said timestamps are pretty useless cache keys in general, so probably just meant as an example. In real code, presumably the cache key would be the query. A WeakMap would work, but I'm not sure that its behavior would be preferable over manual cache size control.